# Is it true that, $A,B\subset X$ are completely seprated iff their closures are?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If $A,B\subset X$ and $\overline{A}, \overline{B}$ are completely seprated, so also are $A,B$. since  $A\subset \overline{A}$, $B\subset \overline{B}$ then, $f(A)\subset f(\overline{A})=0$ and $f(B)\subset f(\overline{B})=1$ for some continuous function $f:X\to [0,1]$. but the converse is true?

Comment: May I ask you what is the differences between disjoited and seperated?

Comment: @BabakSorouh $A,B$ are disjoint when $A\cap B=\varnothing$. $A,B$ are seprated when $\overline{A}\cap B=A\cap \overline{B}=\varnothing$.

Comment: So it is more stronger than being disjoint.

Comment: And completely separated means that there exists a continuous function $f:X\to[0,1]$ with $f(A)=0$ and $f(B)=1$?

Comment: @ThomasE. Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are completely separated, and let $f:X\to[0,1]$ be a continuous function such that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in A$ and $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in B$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}[\{0\}]$ is closed, and certainly $A\subseteq f^{-1}[\{0\}]$, so ... ?

Comment: So $\overline{A}\subseteq \overline{f^{-1}[\{0\}]}\subseteq f^{-1}[\{0\}]$ hence, $f(\overline{A})\subseteq ff^{-1}[\{0\}]\subseteq [\{0\}]=\{0\}$.

Comment: @TXC: Exactly. Or even just ‘$f^{-1}[\{0\}]$ is a closed set containing $A$, so it contains $\operatorname{cl}A$, which $f$ therefore sends to $0$.’

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $A,B\subseteq X$ are completely separated, i.e. there exists a continuous function $f:X\to [0,1]$ with $f(A)=0$ and $f(B)=1$. Recall that continuity is equivalent with $f(\overline{F})\subseteq \overline{f(F)}$ for all $F\subseteq X$. In other words, continuity of $f$ implies $f(\overline{A})\subseteq \overline{f(A)}=\overline{\{0\}}=\{0\}$ and $f(\overline{B})\subseteq \overline{f(B)}=\overline{\{1\}}=\{1\}$. Hence $\overline{A}$ and $\overline{B}$ are also completely separated.