# Open completely separated subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $O$ be an open neighbourhood of $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $V$ be an open neighbourhood of $a$ such that $\overline{V} \subset O$.

$V$ and $\mathbb{R} \setminus \overline{O}$ are disjoint (open) cozero-sets. I want to show that $V$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus \overline{O}$ are completely separated. This question stems from my reading of Proposition 1.1 of

> A.V. Arhangel'skii, *Topological groups and $C$-embeddings*, Top. Appl. vol.115, no.3 pp.265–289, [doi:10.1016/S0166-8641(00)00073-0](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0166-8641(00)00073-0)

I see several references to find a logical relation between open subset of space $X$ and completely separated sets, for example in Gillman and Jerison's [*Rings of continuous functions*](http://books.google.com/books/about/Rings_of_continuous_functions.html?id=k4KnAAAAIAAJ):

1. **Theorem.** Two sets are completely separated if and only if they are 
   contained in disjoint zero-sets.
2. **Urysohn's lemma.** Any two disjoint closed sets in a normal 
   space are completely separated.

But I can't find such a relation for this situation.

In answers to [a previous question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295220/is-it-true-that-a-b-subset-x-are-completely-seprated-iff-their-closures-are), Brian M. Scott and Thomas E. explained that  $A,B\subset X$ are completely separated iff their closures are.

How can I show that  $V$ and $\mathbb{R}\backslash \overline{O}$ are completely separated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the real line $\mathbb{R}$ is [perfectly normal](http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Perfectly_normal_space), it follows that the zero sets are exactly the closed sets.  (In a normal space the zero sets are exactly the closed G<sub>δ</sub> sets, and in a perfectly normal space all closed subsets are G<sub>δ</sub>. See [this other answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/340581).)

So to show that $V$ and $\mathbb{R} \setminus \overline{O}$ are completely separated, it suffices to find disjoint closed sets $F,E$ such that $V \subseteq F$ and $\mathbb{R} \setminus \overline{O} \subseteq E$.

Now just note that

- $\overline{V}$ and $\mathbb{R} \setminus O$ are closed,
- $V \subseteq \overline{V}$ and $\mathbb{R} \setminus \overline{O} \subseteq \mathbb{R} \setminus O$, and
- as $\overline{V} \subseteq O$, it follows that $\overline{V} \cap ( \mathbb{R} \setminus O ) = \varnothing$.